# rqt_plot does not see backends

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, rqt, ubuntu-xenial, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed QWT and its' bindings for both python2 and python3. Moreover I have installed pyqtgraph but no one of them is available in settings. So I stuck to matplotlib which is extremely slow.

Did anyone meet this problem?

P.S. OS is Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248784/rqt_plot-does-not-see-backends/) by [Long Smith](https://answers.ros.org/users/28619/long-smith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-11-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maxikrie](https://answers.ros.org/users/15456/maxikrie/) on 2016-12-15**:
Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this patch will help: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/pull/415

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maxikrie](https://answers.ros.org/users/15456/maxikrie/) on 2017-01-11**:
Works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to take a look to this alternative to rqt_plot. Unfortunately you need to compile it from source for the time being...

https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler

Let me me know if it helps

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1